# Twilio SDK blank exception

Tags: php, phalcon, ratchet, twilio-php

**sdk version 5.4.2**
***API Subdomain: /2010-04-01/Accounts/xxx/Calls/xxx**

We are having an odd issue with our setup. We are using Phalcon, Ratchet and the Twilio PHP sdk.

Our code is approximately as follows.

The client is successfully created and valid.

```
$client = new Client($sid, $token)
```

Then when we run the following code

```
try{
    $call = $client->calls($data)->fetch();
    echo $call->message;
} catch (Exception $e){
    echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
}
```

The only return we get in Ratchet is...

```
An error has occured:
```

This happens anytime we have execute the fetch() line.  It is not throwing an exception that we can check with the try catch block.

We checked debugging directly on the server and the exception is being thrown but is coming back empty

```
object(Twilio\Exceptions\EnvironmentException)#101 (7) {
 ["message":protected]=>
 string(0) ""
 ["string":"Exception":private]=>
 string(0) ""
 ["code":protected]=>
 int(0)
```

I have confirmed that we are using valid data as I used the SID and Token to log directly into the website. While in the above example I have $data I have tried hard coding the SID we are checking in.

---

Edit:

---

We have confirmed the code works on the main Phalcon site, so it seems to be some conflict with Ratchet.

Comment: [Which of these](https://github.com/twilio/twilio-php/blob/5.4.2/Twilio/Http/CurlClient.php#L28-L34) is throwing the exception?

Comment: $call = $client->calls($data)->fetch(); is the one throwing the exception

Comment: That's not what I'm asking. I'm asking which line of code in the linked 5.4.2 source in my previous comment is responsible for the `EnvironmentException`.